# Parse the JSON in Power Apps

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow, json, powerapp, power-automate

I have below output from flow to Power Apps.

```
[
   {\"Name\":\"GHI.docx\",\"Path\":\"/Cont/A/GHI.docx\"},
   {\"Name\":\"Tes1.docx\",\"Path\":\"/Cont/A/Test1.docx\"}
]
```

How can I convert it into a collection?

Comment: How you fetched this data from flow to powerapps?

Comment: I used send Respond to PowerApps action and passed the above JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use to use multiple **Split** functions in Power App in order to parse this string to JSON/collection variable.

It will be a complex logic and according to your data.

Check below link, it will help you to achieve what you want.

[Respond Tabular Data from FLOW to PowerApps without Premium Response action](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cUKtQslS68E)

[Split function in Power Apps](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-split)

Answer (score 0):

My data is different, I used

Clear(datas);
ForAll(records,Collect(datas,
MatchAll(Substitute(Result,"""",""), "ID:(?.*),Start.*Date of first donation:(?.*),Email.*First name:(?.*),Surname:(?.*),Postcode.*Currency of donation:(?.*),Regular donation amount:(?.*),The.*Address 1:(?.*),Freq.*Address 2:(?.*),")))